# How do I scroll to the end of an growing ul in java script

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html-lists

I am writing a html page which is adding li to ul continually using java script. I want the page to scroll to the end of the ul **smoothly**! It shouldn't use jQuery if this is possible.

I tried element.scrollTo, element.scrollTop and some jQuery stuff. All of that didn't work. Nothing I found on the web worked D:

The only thing that works is element.scrollIntoView() but that's not smooth and kind of jumps to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
element.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

PS: It's just an addition to the previous answer.

Comment: Worked out perfectly! Thanks

Comment: You can also try to experiment adding option "block: 'end'" as well. It defines vertical alignment to the bottom of the element. For more info: [scrollIntoView on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 1):

In the page's css put:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

In the JS, you can use:

```
window.scrollBy({ 
  top: 200,
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

You can then call this in a loop if necessary to have constant scrolling, or set a larger scroll amount.

Or, take a look at [Zenscroll](https://zengabor.github.io/zenscroll/).

Comment: Does this really scroll to the end of my ul or to the end of the page?

Comment: @MaxTheGuy If you put this in a loop, possibly that repeats each time you add an element, so that it goes until the end of the page. Or if you know the height of the page and specify the amount accordingly.

Comment: That didn't work, too. Luckily that guy down there helped me. Thanks to you, too.